# Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::getInput()

Tags: joomla4

Since today my Joomla 4 website only shows a blank screen with "error". I've set error_reporting to maximum and now I get the following error:

Error: Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::getInput(): Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::getInput()

I have no clue how I can fix it and I couldn't found any hint using google. I haven't done anything, but maybe there was an automatic update. I'm using PHP 8.2.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The solution was to migrate to Word Press :-)

Comment: ouch. thx, I reinstalled the entire CMS and manually migrated the content :(